# Storing data coming from the server in form of JSON onto Android Sqlite database

Tags: android, json, sqlite, parsing, listview

I have never worked on SQlite android database. So if possible I would greatly appreciate some spoon feeding/pointers in this question.

I have a service which gives me a list of state names in form of `JSON` which I need to parse and store onto a database in android and show it onto a `ListView`.
Currently am successfully been able to just parse the `JSON` data as it comes and then show it directly onto a `ListView` with the help of this code below:

```
public class OpenMeetingsListActivity extends ListActivity 
{

    private Context context;
    private static String url = "http://myurl.com/mycountry/statelist.php";

    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_SN = "sn";
    JSONArray posts = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_header);
        t.setText("Select Your State");

        new ProgressTask(OpenMeetingsListActivity.this).execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String stateSelected = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sn)).getText().toString();

        String url="http://myurl.com/mycountry/citylist.php?stname="+URLEncoder.encode(stateSelected);

        Intent intent=new Intent(OpenMeetingsListActivity.this,OpenMeetingsListActivity_Items.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        intent.putExtra("stateSelected",stateSelected);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        OpenMeetingsListActivity op;


        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {

            Log.i("1", "Called");
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

        /** application context. */
        private Context context;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                    R.layout.list_openmeeting_item, new String[] { TAG_SN }, new int[] {
                    R.id.sn });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // selecting single ListView item
            lv = getListView(); 

        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


            try {
                posts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {

                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String sn = c.getString(TAG_SN);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_SN, sn);
                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } }catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return null;

        }

    }



}
```

Now The change that I need to make in this code or say what I need to add to this code is I need to store the JSON data thats coming from the link

> http://myurl.com/mycountry/statelist.php

onto a database in android first. Then I need to get that data from the database and display it onto a `ListView` in android.

After am done with that I need to again parse an url such as

> http://myurl.com/mycountry/citylist.php?stname="+URLEncoder.encode(stateSelected)

in the next class to show the respective city in the respective states(state that you selected in the class above). The above url gives the names of the cities in form of `JSON` which needs to be again parsed and stored onto a database and displayed onto a `ListView`.

Finally when one clicks on the name of a city in the ListView it redirects to the third and final class which forms this url below

> http://myurl.com/mycountry/openmeet.php?reg="+state+"&cityvalid="+city

using the information provided by the previous two classes. This url gives some `JSON` data which again needs to parsed, stored and displayed onto a `ListView`.

Thus my application here has three classes:
1. In the first class the state names are displayed onto a View.
2. In the second class respective city names are displayed onto a View depending upon which State was selected in the previous class.
3. In the third class a combination url of selected state and selected city gives information details related to that particular city.

**All the data is coming from the server**.

I have been able to achieve this functionality by simply displaying the data directly coming from the server onto a `ListView` as it comes. Now I need to store it first onto a database and then show it on a `ListView` for all three classes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


            try {
                posts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {

                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String sn = c.getString(TAG_SN);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_SN, sn);
                    jsonlist.add(map);

                    //Just Put your database insert query here
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(TAG_SN, sn);
                    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

                } }catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return null;

        }
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

> I have been able to achieve this functionality by simply displaying
>   the data directly coming from the server onto a ListView as it comes.
>   Now I need to store it first onto a database and then show it on a
>   `ListView` for all three classes.

IMHO , you just need to know how does android **sqlite** *CRUD* operations work, Below are some steps that you may take to get the problem resolved :

- Google a **sqlite-android tutorial**.
- AFAIK you have knowledge of **parsing the json** so you can get the data from the json file **(name-value pairs)**
- These **names** are going to be **columns in sqlite db**
- The **values** associated with the **names** in the `json` data would be the **datasets** in columns.
- To populate the data to the `ListView` again you have to fetch (read) the data from sqlite and then using `Asynctask` you can populate it again